# C# WinSCP .NET assembly Download the latest file from the latest directory

Tags: c#, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm new to WinSCP. I'm facing difficulty of making the remote path to dynamic because the folder in my FTP is generated following by `root/data/20160222/00(hour)/00(minute)/test.json*`

This path also always contain more than one files.

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "192.168.1.100",
    UserName = "admin",  
    Password = "admin",      
};

string localPath = @"c:\\gatewayftp\\json";
// this path needs to take the latest date and the latest hour and minutes every day
string remotePath = "/data/20160228/2100/59"
```

Now I set fixed path, struggle for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the WinSCP .NET assembly example for [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#csharp):

```
string remotePath = "/data";
// In each of three levels of hierarchy...
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // ... pick the last file/directory alphabetically
    // (use .LastWriteTime instead of .Name to pick the latest file/directory by time)
    remotePath +=
        "/" + 
        session.ListDirectory(remotePath).Files
            .OrderByDescending(file => file.Name).First().Name;
}
```

See also the [documentation for `Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory).

Comment: i get an exception error on WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Error listing directory ' data/20160228/ ---> winSCP.SessionException: Could not retieve directory listing. 
Error changing directory

Comment: Enable logging (`Session.SessionLogPath`) and attach the log to your question.

Comment: thanks Martin problem solve by using c# function datetime. please close this topic thank you.

Comment: @NewUser Only you can close the topic. By accepting an answer (you can post your own, if needed).

Comment: i have try several options of string "path" send to FTP for request the latest file in the directory:
the string is follow as below:

     string remotePath = "/data/" + TimeGet.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "/" + TimeGet.ToString("HH00") + "/" + TimeGet.ToString("mm");

hope this help someone.